# C++ and Swift: How are structs handled in C++ stack frames? Are the complications of struct inheritance why Swift does not support struct inheritance?

Tags: c++, swift, memory-model, stack-frame

At a recent developer meet up the topic of `struct` inheritance in Swift (or more precisely the lack of `struct` inheritance in Swift) was briefly discussed. I assumed that the reason why Swift does not support `struct` inheritance is because:

- `struct`s are value types
- value types are copied between stack frames
- inheritance would mean that the size of a `struct` could vary (e.g. if `Lorry` inherits from `Vehicle` and `Lorry` adds `.weightCapacity` then `Lorry` will require more space than `Vehicle`)
- Having value type parameters with a size that is not known at compile time would complicate stack frame construction for the caller and accessing the data for the callee

I assume that it is because of these complications, which presumably would add extra operations to every function call that involves a `struct` and thus degrade performance, that Swift does not allow `struct` inheritance. Is this reasoning correct?

But then I though about C++. C++ does allow `struct` inheritance and C++ is very performance focused. This makes me think that my reasoning for Swift not allowing `struct` inheritance is wrong. How does C++ achieved `struct` inheritance without negatively impacting performance?

Answer (score 4):

> How does C++ achieved struct inheritance without negatively impacting performance?

In C++, the compiler *always* knows the size of a `struct`.  But when a base class is copied by value, the object gets "sliced": only members of the base class are copied, and the new object is not in any way related to the original object's derived class.

So if a function wants to do something with a `Vehicle` without slicing off its extra identity, it must use a pointer or reference to `Vehicle` as the function parameter type or return type.  But at that point you no longer have "value types copied between stack frames".

Answer (score 0):

Since structs are value types, you are supposed to copy them into the function and back. So you could call a non-mutating method with the derived struct, but wouldn't be able to return a derived value from it, so

```
struct Vehicle {
   var color: Color

   mutating func paintWhite() {
       self.color = .White
   } 
}


struct Lorry: Vehicle ...

var lorry = Lorry(color:.Blue)
lorry.paintWhite() // <- wouldn't work, as paintWhite takes inout Vehicle
```

Without the ability to call mutating methods structs would be much less useful and much more confusing.